# converting the values in my array into INT

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have as array

```
Y =[[ 5.  0.  4.  1.  9.  2.  1.  3.  1.  4.  3.  5.  3.  6.  1.  7.  2.  8.
   6.  9.  4.  0.  9.  1.  1.  2.  4.  3.  2.  7.  3.  8.  6.  9.  0.  5.
   6.  0.  7.  6.  1.  8.  7.  9.  3.  9.  8.  5.  9.  3.  3.  0.  7.  4.
   9.  8.  0.  9.  4.  1.  4.  4.  6.  0.  4.  5.  6.  1.  0.  0.  1.  7.
   1.  6.  3.  0.  2.  1.  1.  7.  9.  0.  2.  6.  7.  8.  3.  9.  0.  4.
   6.  7.  4.  6.  8.  0.  7.  8.  3.  1.  1.  2.  3.]]
```

Then I use the command: `Y.astype(int)`

When printing Y after the astype command I still have as result 5. 0. 4. and so on. But what I want is 5 0 4 etc...

What do I wrong?

Comment: Have you assigned back, to `Y`, i.e. `Y = Y.astype(int)` ?

Answer (score 1):

[`numpy.astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) returns a copy of the array. It does not manipulate your array in-place. So you have to assign the value to a variable:

```
Y = Y.astype(int)
```

Answer (score -2):

Ok, if we have numpy here and something like that:

```
Y = np.array([5., 0., 4., 1., 9.])
```

We can convert each element of array to int like this:

```
map(int, Y)
```

To get this result:

```
[5, 0, 4, 1, 9]
```

Comment: What do you mean. I have an output Y = [[5. 0. 4. etc]] but on one way or another I want to have as output Y = [[5 0 4 etc... ]] How can I do that?

Comment: @Ilse You can't specify an array like you did. Show the whole example please.

Comment: ok I will put the code in Answer your question because I can't put the code in the Comment

Comment: Y = np.array([5., 0., 4., 1., 9.]) has done what I wanted. tnx